# Keeping multiple MySQL database schema's synced

Tags: php, mysql, schema

Is there a way to keep a lot of MySQL database schema's (not the data) synchronized so that I can update them all at once?

For example, let's say you have a lot of companies each with their own database (with their own data), but the structure of these databases have to always be the same to work with the (common) application software.

These databases are also distributed across a lot of different machines, so I can't just connect and do a `SHOW DATABASES` and then execute the query on each matching DB.

Is there a way to achieve this, preferably with PHP or Node.js?

Comment: This sounds like it would be part of the deployment scenario for the application, not functionality that would be included in the application or database itself.  When updating an instance of the application, the deployment should also update the instance(s) of the database used by that instance of the application.

Comment: Agree with @David that this might be good as part of application distribution.  But other solutions might depend on why they're different. Are local changes being made, or is this really a software update issue? What is the nature of the changes that are being made?  Also, sure the DBs are distributed across a bunch of different machines, but are they behind different firewalls?  Even though they're distributed, you *could* connect and execute queries (assuming network permissions)